# R, rbinom(), NA, and matrices: How to ignore NA yet retain them

Tags: r, matrix

I am putting some values in a matrix through a binomial probability expression.  The problem is that I have some NA values that I need to keep in my matrix, but rbinom() returns an error when NA is inputted.

My algorithm consists of the following:

- (1) start with a matrix of values in one column.
- (2) double the
  values in that matrix.
- (3) select a random value from a binomial
  probability of 0.5.
- ... some more things that are uneccessary

Here is a reproducible example.

```
set.seed(10)
xn <- matrix(c(NA, 100, 100, 100, 100, NA, NA, 100, 100, NA), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2)
dup <- xn * 2 
z <- matrix(rbinom(n=rep(1,length(dup)), size = as.vector(dup), prob = 0.5), nrow = nrow(dup))
Warning message:
In rbinom(n = rep(1, length(dup)), size = as.vector(dup), prob = 0.5) :
  NAs produced
```

I thought about only selecting the values in the matrix that have actual values.

```
set.seed(6)
xn_bin <- rbinom(n=rep(1,length(dup[-which(is.na(dup))])), size = as.vector(dup[-which(is.na(dup))]),prob = 0.5)
```

I don't know how to get the matrix back together since I need take the results from xn_bin and put them back into the same position in a new matrix as the dup values were located inputted into rbinom().

If that does not make any sense.  xn_bin will give the values:
     xn_bin
     [1] 101 115 112  98 103 103

dup will give:

```
dup
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA  200
[2,]  200  200
[3,]  200   NA
[4,]   NA  200
[5,]  200   NA
```

I want the final matrix to have the values from xn_bin and the NA values from xn:

```
         [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   101
[2,]   115  112
[3,]   98   NA
[4,]   NA   103
[5,]   103  NA
```

Any idea how to do this effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the order is not the same but position in the matrix structure is as desired and since this is a random process that should not be determined by positon I do not see why this result is not as valid as your ordering (R matrices being filled by column rather than by row):

```
 xn_bin <- z

 set.seed(6)
 xn_bin[ !is.na(z) ] <- rbinom(n=rep(1,length(dup[-which(is.na(dup))])), 
                               size = as.vector(dup[-which(is.na(dup))]),prob = 0.5)
 xn_bin
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  NaN   98
[2,]  101  103
[3,]  115  NaN
[4,]  NaN  103
[5,]  112  NaN
```

Comment: Would it be possible to arrange by row?  Each column represents the growth in a population while each row is replicates of different populations.  Thus, if ordering by column then the values are being mixed up between the different populations.

Comment: Also, what is z defined as?  In my example, it is not defined as an error is produced.

Comment: First question: The order of processing and R matrix is along columns, so I believe my ordering is correct and yours is wrong. Second question: You defined `z`. ??? I just made a copy of it to have placeholders for the values in the right place.